# Higher-order functions in C++, using std::wcout fails with error C2248

Tags: c++, functional-programming, visual-c++-2010

I'm playing around with implementing functional-style stuff in C++. At the moment, I'm looking at a continuation-passing style for enumerating files.

I've got some code that looks like this:

```
namespace directory
{
    void find_files(
        std::wstring &path,
        std::function<void (std::wstring)> process)
    {
        boost::filesystem::directory_iterator begin(path);
        boost::filesystem::directory_iterator end;

        std::for_each(begin, end, process);
    }
}
```

Then I'm calling it like this:

```
directory::find_files(source_root, display_file_details(std::wcout));
```

...where `display_file_details` is defined like this:

```
std::function<void (std::wstring)>
    display_file_details(std::wostream out)
{
    return [&out] (std::wstring path) { out << path << std::endl; };
}
```

The plan is to pass a continuation to `find_files`, but to be able to pass composed functions into it.

But I get the error:

```
error C2248: 'std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits>::basic_ios' :
    cannot access private member declared in
    class 'std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits>'
```

What am I doing wrong? Am I insane for trying this?

Note: my functional terminology (higher-order, continuations, etc.) is probably wrong. Feel free to correct me.

Comment: You can't pass a wostream by value.  Only by reference.   `std::wostream& out`

Comment: Why is `display_file_details` a generator instead of an actual function?

Comment: Because I'm playing around and that's how I'd have done it in functional-style C# or F#. If I was thinking C++03, I could have used `bind`, I guess.

Comment: oh, I failed to notice that `display_file_details` takes a different parameter than it's returned function.  Nevermind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `display_file_details`, you need to take your wostream by reference.  iostream copy constructors are private.

Answer (score 4):

Upon looking more deeply into the compiler output, I found this:

```
This diagnostic occurred in the compiler generated function
    'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::
        basic_ostream(const std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &)'
```

It turns out that basic_ostream doesn't have an available copy constructor.

Changing `std::wostream out` to `std::wostream & out` fixes it. At least to the point that I get a bunch of other errors. These were easily fixed by:

```
std::for_each(begin, end,
    [&process] (boost::filesystem::directory_entry d)
    { process(d.path().wstring()); });
```